# HOW TO USE UI COMPONENTS?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, ui-form

guys i'm learning how to use ui components and following doubts arose, i found a code in the magento documentation of a form, but the documents is difficult to understand and does not explain what is necessary to change for me to use in a module, the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">category_form.category_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Category Information</item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
        <item name="reverseMetadataMerge" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <buttons>
            <button name="save" class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\SaveButton"/>
            <button name="delete" class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\DeleteButton"/>
        </buttons>
        <namespace>category_form</namespace>
        <dataScope>data</dataScope>
        <deps>
            <dep>category_form.category_form_data_source</dep>
        </deps>
    </settings>
    <dataSource name="category_form_data_source">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <validateUrl path="catalog/category/validate"/>
            <submitUrl path="catalog/category/save"/>
        </settings>
        <dataProvider class="Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider" name="category_form_data_source">
            <settings>
                <requestFieldName>id</requestFieldName>
                <primaryFieldName>entity_id</primaryFieldName>
            </settings>
        </dataProvider>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="general" sortOrder="5">
        <settings>
            <collapsible>false</collapsible>
            <label/>
        </settings>
        <field name="id" formElement="hidden">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
            </settings>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

and a question I have is how to use the DataSource in magento 2? Why do I have to use it? What is it for?

Answer (score 0):

The User of data source, is providing the data collection to the magento UI_grid component.
So it load the data from data source and show the data to the grid as the column you mention into your file.

You can take the reference of the magento default grid like product, order, invoice etc.